# Ruby on Rails Scaffold with number as a db header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error, scaffolding

I'm trying to generate a scaffolding in RoR with numbers as headings:

```
rails g scaffold company user_id:integer 2010:text
```

It runs the scaffolding correctly, but when I try to do a migration I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
```

Am I just doing something wrong or can't one name a heading a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such migration violates ruby syntax at first. But even for pure SQL you can't provide heading starts with number. For example, you can find description in [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($).

Comment: Thanks @Tensho , will try the underscore first. Unfortunate, because I have a db with over a hundred headings and a file I need to import where the headings are numbers so wanted to Keep it Simple. Guess thats not an option...